# Lines for all the rows in separate columns

Tags: tables, multirow, chemistry

Is it possible to have lines for all the rows in the last two columns 7 and 8?
Is it also possible to have an empty space in the first column at the last two rows?

```
\begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \caption{\textit{Beräkning av K$_{OW}$}.}
        \begin{tabular}[ht]{|c!{\vrule width 2pt}c|c|c|c!{\vrule width 2pt}c|c|c|}
            \hline
            
 \multirow{7}{*}{ \rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Tetrabutyl}} } & Bindning & f$_i$  & n$_i$ & Produkt & \multirow{7}{*}{ \rotatebox{90}{\textbf{PFBS}} } &  n$_i$ & Produkt   \\ \cline{2-5}
 &-CH$_3$  &0,5473  &4 &2,1892 &  & &\\ \cline{2-5}
 &-CH$_2$  &0,4911  & 12& 5,8932 & & &\\ \cline{2-5}
 &-SO$_2$O &-0,7250 &1 & -0,7250 & & &\\ \cline{2-5}
 &-F       &-0,0031 &9 & -0,0279 & & &\\ \cline{2-5}
 &-P=O     & -2,4239 & 1 & -2,4239 & & &\\ \cline{2-5}
 &-O-H     & -1,4086& - & - &    & &\\ \hline


 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Koefficient} & 0,229   \\ \cline{1-5}
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Summa} & 5,1346  \\ \cline{1-8}



        \end{tabular}
        \label{tabell: Fysiokemiska}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your document to an MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but complete self contained document) with your table, which we can compile as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,multirow}
\usepackage{mhchem}       % for '\ce' macro, for chemical compounts
\usepackage{letterspace}  % for '\textls' macro
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
 \setlength\extrarowheight{1.6pt} %  2pt seems too thick
 \centering
 \caption{\textit{Beräkning av K\textsubscript{OW}}.\strut}
 \label{tabell:Fysiokemiska}
 \begin{tabular}{|c !{\vrule width1.6pt}
                  l|
                  S[table-format=-1.4]|
                  S[table-format= 2.0]|
                  S[table-format=-1.4] !{\vrule width1.6pt}
                  c|
                  c|
                  c|}
 \hline        
   \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Tetrabutyl }}} 
 & {Bindning} & {$f_i$} & {$n_i$} & {Produkt}
 & \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{\textls{PFBS }}}} 
 & $n_i$ & Produkt \\                          \cline{2-5} \cline{7-8}
 &-\ce{CH3}  &  0,5473  &  4&  2,1892 & & & \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-8}
 &-\ce{CH2}  &  0,4911  & 12&  5,8932 & & & \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-8}
 &-\ce{SO2O} & -0,7250  &  1& -0,7250 & & & \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-8}
 &-\ce{F}    & -0,0031  &  9& -0,0279 & & & \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-8}
 &-\ce{P=O}  & -2,4239  &  1& -2,4239 & & & \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-8}
 &-\ce{O-H}  & -1,4086  &{--}& {--}   & & & \\ \hline
 \multicolumn{1}{c !{\vrule width1.6pt}}{}
 & \multicolumn{3}{r|}{Koefficient} & 0,229  \\ \cline{2-5}
 \multicolumn{1}{c !{\vrule width1.6pt}}{}
 & \multicolumn{3}{r|}{Summa}       & 5,1346 \\ \cline{2-5}
 \end{tabular}
 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Always it is necessary insert to table all ampersands: n-1 if you have n columns. Adding missed ampersands in the last two rows -- there are missed three `&`, will solve your problem.

However, your table can be done nicer (at least to my opinion), if you consider in it design packages `siunitx`, `mhchem` and `makecell` and for caption `caption`:

[image]

```
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
\caption{Beräkning av $K_{OW}$.}
\label{tabell: Fysiokemiska}
\begin{tabular}{|c!{\vrule width 2pt}l|S[table-format=-1.4]|
                                       S[table-format= 2.0]|
                                       S[table-format=-1.4]!{\vrule width 2pt}
                                       c|c|c|}
    \hline
 \multirow{7}{*}{ \rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Tetrabutyl}} } 
    & Bindning      & {$f_i$}   & {$n_i$} & {Produkt} & \multirow{7}{*}{ \rotatebox{90}{\textbf{PFBS}} } 
                                                        & $n_i$ & Produkt   \\ \cline{2-5}
    & \ce{-CH3}     &  0,5473   &  4    &  2,1892   &   &       &\\ \cline{2-5}
    & \ce{-CH2}     &  0,4911   & 12    &  5,8932   &   &       &\\ \cline{2-5}
    & \ce{-SO2O}    & -0,7250   &  1    & -0,7250   &   &       &\\ \cline{2-5}
    & \ce{-F}       & -0,0031   &  9    & -0,0279   &   &       &\\ \cline{2-5}
    & \ce{-P-O}     & -2,4239   &  1    & -2,4239   &   &       &\\ \cline{2-5}
    & \ce{-O=H}     & -1,4086   & {--}  & {--}      &   &       &\\ 
    \hline
\mcc[4]{Koefficient}            & 0,229             &   &       &\\ \hline
\mcc[4]{Summa}                  & 5,1346            &   &       &\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```